# OS X - Make all screens combined

Tags: macos, display

Is there any way to make all screens connected to Mac function as one, so full screen apps (like iTunes Visualizer) can extend over all monitors? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the most qualified to speak on multiple displays but the way I know to do it is:

- System Preferences
- Mission Control
- **Uncheck** Displays have separate spaces
- Log out & back in